# Get all records data to a Widget without making a new Query in the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-widget

I have 2 Models Product and Category with - ManyToMany Relation Product-Category and self ForeignKey for Category

```
 class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='parent category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and the Product creation form:

```
class ProductModelForm(ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = ['categories', 'name', 'short_description', 'description']
            widgets = {
                'categories': MyWidget,
            }
```

By default ManyToMany becomes ModelMultipleChoiceField and coresponds to SelectMultiple Widget.

I'm creating a new widget inheriting from SelectMultiple.

My issue is that in all widgets by default Django send from the record just the value defined inside `def __str__` on the Model. In case of Select also pk.

```
(None, [{'name': 'categories', 'value': 7, 'label': 'Category 2', 'selected': True, 'index': '1', 'attrs': {'selected': True}, 'type': 'select', 'template_name': 'django/forms/widgets/select_option.html'}]
```

I need to have in the Widget also other information like the parent value.

Off course I can make another query and get the data from the database, but that means I have 2 queries one done by me and one by Django.

Is there any way to make Django To send all record data to the widget instead of just what was defined in `__str__` ?

Changing `__str__` is not an option because it use also in other places and in admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not very easy: A `ModelChoiceField` (and `ModelMultipleChoiceField`) takes a `queryset` parameter that by default is the model's `default_manager` (`Category.objects.all()`). The queryset is consumed when the `choices` are produced for the widget, using the `ModelChoiceIterator`. That indeed only returns a 2-tuple of the object's `id` and `label` for each object in the queryset.

So to make sure there's only one query to the database you'd have to subclass `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to use a subclass of `ModelChoiceIterator` which returns a 3-tuple (or more) with the parameters you need. Then make sure you also subclass the `__init__()` method of `ChoiceWidget` (in your case `SelectMultiple`) to split the tuple again into a 2-tuple to assign to `self.choices` and the other values to set as widget attributes (`self.attrs`) so you can use them in your template.

Not sure this is worth the optimisation you get, especially if you use a good caching mechanism you wouldn't actually hit your db twice if you perform `Category.objects.all()` two times.

Comment: I thought about subclassing the ModelMultipleChoiceField, but is "called" by ManytoMany(using fields_for_model mehod) where I don't see how I can overwrite to change the default field without affecting the core or other parts.

Comment: well, you can just [override the form field to use in your form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields): just add `categories = MyOwnModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())` at the top of your form.

Comment: but again, to be honest, it's a nice exercise to understand the inner workings of Django, but I wouldn't go this way :-) Add good caching and you don't have to worry about this.